# Reference Frontmatter in React MDX Markdown File

Tags: reactjs, markdown, yaml-front-matter, mdxjs

I have set up a next.js markdown blog using mdx:  https://mdxjs.com/.

I would like to be able to reference data in the frontmatter section within the mdx file itself.  Something like this:

```
// my-file.mdx
---
title: "My blog post title"

# {title} // should be replaced by the frontmatter title
```

Now, this does not work.  It does NOT replace `{title}` with the title found in the frontmatter (i.e,. `My blog post title`).  What I am wondering is whether or not there is a way to do this and, if so, how?

Thanks.

Comment: Also wondered this, did you find an answer @Moshe?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [Docusaurus docs page on available exports](https://docusaurus.io/docs/markdown-features/react#available-exports). For your example, `title` is available as `<p>{contentTitle}</p>`. For more specific keys, you can use something like:

`<p>{Object.entries(frontMatter).find(frontmatter => frontmatter[0] === 'description'}</p>`

to retrieve, in this example, the description. (Replace html `<p>` tag with whatever tag is appropriate.)

Comment: your linked page says that `frontMatter` is available as a global. So to use data, it's acutally a lot easier. `<p>{frontMatter.<property>}</p>`

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MDX with Next.js 13 and spent too much time looking for a complicated solution for accessing frontmatter within MDX, like using remark-mdx-frontmatter as per https://mdxjs.com/guides/frontmatter/. But if you're using [gray-matter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gray-matter) with Next 13 for your frontmatter, the frontmatter object is exposed to the MDX markdown body by default. So if your MDX has this frontmatter:

```
---
date: 'September 9, 2023'
---
```

You can access it from the MDX body with:

```
{frontmatter.date}
```